# I want to change name of the view in the IB. Please see the screenshot

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I want to rename View to View1. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure what you are planning to do. If you want to have this view renamed in IB objects inspector:

1. Select the view
2. open right panel
3. go to the Identity Inspector(3rd icon)
4. fill Identity->Label (with placeholder "Xcode Specific Label").

However, if you want to access the view from view controller(use it in code), you should read about IBOutlets.

Answer (score 2):

in the identity inspector, there's a section called "Identity". in that section is a textfield for "Label". changing that will change the name that appears in xcode. note that this is only something that has effect in xcode - it doesn't change anything about how the view is used in the app. is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think the operator wants to change the name in the outline. This can be done as described but it is no longer under Identity but Document.